# How to change Linear Units

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, linear-referencing, map-unit

I have an ESRI feature class whose coordinates are 38.263, -122.672 Meters.  When I load it into a data frame that uses the GCS_NAD_1983_NSRS2007 datum and the NAD_1983_NSRS2007_California_Teale_Albers projection, it shows up a) very very small, and b) in the Sierra Nevada foothills rather than near San Fancisco Bay (which is at 38 degrees North and 122 degrees West).  I think the problem would be solved if the feature class's linear unit was changed from Meter to Degree.  How do I do this?

Comment: I just tried editing the .prj file.   I changed UNIT["Foot",1.0]] to UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]], but this has had no effect.

Comment: First rule of .prj file editing: Don't do it.
Second rule of .prj editing (Experts only): Don't do it (yet).  
Random changes are not going to help.

Answer (score 4):

Just assign it a geographic coordinate system like NAD 1983 (NSRS2007) or NAD 1983 (2011) by using the data's property page in ArcCatalog or the Define Projection tool.

It sounds like the feature class has a projected coordinate system assigned to it. That's not correct.

If the "x" values are around 38 and the "y" values are around -122, you have a bigger problem, because latitude values (like 38) should be assigned to "y" and longitude values to "x".